# yearsBase is not recognised? Introduction to Machine Learning and Python with Azure Notebooks climate change question

Tags: python, azure

I've followed the instructions so far on the course but for some reason it's saying yearsBase isn't defined and keeps showing an error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayVHp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you never ran the 2nd cell there.   Try running all of the cells again.